# Asp.Net MemoryCache being evicted for no apparent reason

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, memorycache

I was testing out a bit the `System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache`, to see how it works.

I created a cache as below:

```
            NameValueCollection config = new NameValueCollection();
            config.Add("cacheMemoryLimitMegabytes", Convert.ToString(250));
            config.Add("pollingInterval", Convert.ToString("00:00:17"));
            config.Add("physicalMemoryLimitPercentage", Convert.ToString(2));
            _m_memoryCacheToUse = new MemoryCache("MemCache",config);
```

I created a test web page, which basically I can specify an amount of items of roughly 1KB memory size (byte array of 1000) to create in cache.  My machine has 12GB of RAM, and current RAM usage is around 40% which leaves me a lot of memory to play with.  From the above settings, I should be using 250MB of ram, or 2% of my physical memory.  For some reason, when I read the settings (`cache.PhysicalMemoryLimit`) it shows 3% not 2%.   2% should equal 245MB, while 3% should equal to 368MB.

First of all, I'm not sure how it works.  Default values are 99% for `PhysicalMemoryLimit` and the `CacheMemoryLimitMegabytes` is set at 7.8GB on my PC.  So I decided to override both settings.  I don't know how it works when you set them both, so I tried with similar values.

I am inserting 50,000 items in cache, as per below:

```
    void btnGenerateCacheStressTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TimeSpan slidingExpiration = new TimeSpan(24, 1, 1, 1);
        DateTimeOffset expirationDate = DateTimeOffset.MaxValue;
        int itemsToGenerate = Convert.ToInt32(txtItemsToGenerate.Text);
        var cache = MemCacheToUseToUse;

        Random rnd = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < itemsToGenerate; i++)
        {
            CacheItemPolicy policy = new CacheItemPolicy();
            policy.Priority = CacheItemPriority.Default;
            policy.RemovedCallback += CacheEntryRemovedCallback;
            policy.SlidingExpiration = slidingExpiration;
            policy.AbsoluteExpiration = expirationDate;

            string regionName = null;
            string rndKey = ("stressTest-Data-" + DateTime.Now.Ticks + "-" + i);

            byte[] bytesArray = new byte[1000];
            rnd.NextBytes(bytesArray);


            cache.Add(rndKey, bytesArray, policy, regionName);
        }

    }
```

I experimented with both `NoSlidingExpiration`, and defining a sliding expiration.  50,000 of items should equate to roughly 50 - 70MB I guess adding up some overheads.  That is far less than the 256MB I am allowing for cache.  Yet, after a few seconds, the `CacheEntryRemovedCallback` gets called and cache goes down to even just 1000 items sometimes.  The `RemovedReason` is `Evicted`, which MSDN says is done when (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.cacheentryremovedreason(v=vs.110).aspx)

It shouldn't be approaching such limits. Why are they being evicted?

Comment: in my studies of `MemoryCache` I learned that setting BOTH the MB and percent limit didn't work well. Have you tried setting just one (either 2% of 250 MB)?

Comment: I tried as well as below
 
 config.Add("cacheMemoryLimitMegabytes", Convert.ToString(1000));
                config.Add("pollingInterval", Convert.ToString("00:00:17"));

Comment: That's quite weird. What if you tried setting no sliding or absolute expiration. Will it work then?

Comment: Sorry comment got sent early by mistake and couldn't reedit. I tried as well with `cacheMemoryLimitMegabytes` set to 1000, and no physicalMemoryPercentage in config.  When reading the value, this got set to 20.  However, items still got evicted after a few seconds once I add 100,000 of those test items.  That should be a far cry from the 1GB, or 20% of 12GB which is 2.4GB. I'm using byte arrays, so I guess 100,000 shouldn't take at most more than 150-200MB.

Comment: Yes, I've tried as well with not setting any sliding / absolute expiration when creating the policy.  Then again, the reason for that should be `Expired` not `Evicted` as specified in the same MSDN article.

Comment: Eviction would indeed indicate memory pressure. Very strange. Maybe 32 bit app and therefore 4gb addresssable and so 2% would be like 82 mb?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64499/discussion-between-karl-cassar-and-haney).

Comment: Hi did you find any reason ??? i have same problem and it almost gave me a heart attack :(

Comment: @PouyaSamie No unfortunately the problem still persisted every now and then.  However, by time the cache does seem to clear.  I assumed that the issue could be in how it calculates memory usage.

Comment: We have the same problem. And it's causing some terrible really terrible garbage collection performance problems.